# Do not quite understand how we pass objects as arguments in this program (Java)

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class PassingObjects {

    double height;
    double width;
    double length;

    public PassingObjects(double height, double length, double width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public PassingObjects(PassingObjects obj) {
        height = obj.height;
        length = obj.length;
        width = obj.width;
     }

    public void calculateVolume() {
        System.out.println(this.length * this.width * this.height);
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         PassingObjects obj = new PassingObjects(30, 40, 10);
         PassingObjects obj2 = new PassingObjects(obj);

         obj.calculateVolume();
         obj2.calculateVolume();


  }

}
```

Why do I get the same value when I run the `calculateVolume()` method from both the objects?

I do not understand how passing `obj` in to the constructor parameters allows the compiler to know that I want 30, 40 and 10 to be passed in as parameters.

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code? That might help you. (Hint: you're *not* passing 30, 40 and 10. You're passing a reference to the existing object, and the constructor is using that as the source of the height/width/length...)

Comment: Can you explain, in simple words, what the constructor `public PassingObjects(PassingObjects obj)` does?

Comment: @BoristheSpider It sets the values of height, length and width. It gets the values from the obj object. Also, are obj and obj2 the actual names of the objects or are they references to objects that do not have a name?

Comment: So you have your answer. "_obj and obj2 the actual names of the objects or are they references to objects_" - I don't understand the question; what is an object name?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I created instances of the PassingObjects class and name them obj and obj2. Are obj and obj2 actual objects or do we use the names of obj and obj2 as a reference to an object? I guess I am confused about the difference between an object and an object reference.

Comment: I still don't get it. An `Object` is a `class` - you created two instances of the class `PassingObjects` and assigned them to two variables named `obj1` and `obj2`. How can a variable name be anything other than a name for a variable?

Comment: My apologies. So I created two objects and named them obj1 and obj2?  Or did I create two instances of the object? What is the difference between an object reference and an actual object?

Comment: @StephenPeterWisniewski: A variable (the "name") is a reference to an object in memory.  Two variables *can* point to the same object.  But there's nothing in the code posted which would cause that.  So it's not really clear what the confusion is.  In `main` you are creating an object, then creating a second object using the properties of the first object.  So you have two objects with matching properties.

Comment: @David Yeah. The question was outside of the scope of the code provided here. Crystal clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the same value because `public PassingObjects(PassingObjects obj)` is a **copy-constructor**, which initializes the new object with the same values as the object given as the parameter.

---

```
height = obj.height;
length = obj.length;
width = obj.width;
```

Here you set the values of the variables from the parameter object to this new object. So the `calculateVolume()` method will return the same value.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Thank you!